# required field validator for hidden dropdown selection

Tags: jquery, forms, drop-down-menu, hidden-field, requiredfieldvalidator

I have the code below so when visitor selects "domestic" a hidden dropdown selection appears for domestic. If the visitor selects "student" then another hidden dropdown selection appears instead. To see how it works, you can [check it out here](http://urbanlocker.co.uk/testingfordropdownrequired.php)
I also use a jquery validator so if there is a field or dropdown menu not chosen then it gives a pop up. But because only one of the hidden fields can be selected (either the ones related to student or domestic) this validator always gives the pop up. What can I do so the pop up works if none of the selections of these hidden dropdown menus is chosen.

The jquery validator that I use is as below:

```
<script>


function formCheck(formobj){

var x=document.forms["form1"]["email"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");

var fieldRequired = Array("reason1",  "reason2");
// Enter field description to appear in the dialog box



var fieldDescription = Array("Reason 1",  "Reason 2");

// dialog message
var alertMsg = "Please complete all fields and enter a valid email address";

var l_Msg = alertMsg.length;

for (var i = 0; i < fieldRequired.length; i++){
    var obj = formobj.elements[fieldRequired[i]];
    if (obj){
        switch(obj.type){
        case "select-one":
            if (obj.selectedIndex == -1 || obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value == ""){
                alertMsg += "  " + "\n";
            }
            break;
        case "select-multiple":
            if (obj.selectedIndex == -1){
                alertMsg += "  " + "\n";
            }
            break;

        case "text":
            case "textarea":
            if (obj.value == "" || obj.value == null || atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length){
                alertMsg += "  " +  "\n";
            }
            break;

        default:
        }
        if (obj.type == undefined){
            var blnchecked = false;
            for (var j = 0; j < obj.length; j++){
                if (obj[j].checked){
                    blnchecked = true;
                }
            }
            if (!blnchecked){
                alertMsg += "  "  + "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}

if (alertMsg.length == l_Msg){
    return true;
}else{
    alert(alertMsg);
    return false;
}


}
// -->
</script>
```

Also the code for the html part is as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    /* <![CDATA[ */
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#storagetype").change(function(){

            if ($(this).val() == "student" ) {

                $("#hidestudent").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect

            } else {

                $("#hidestudent").slideUp("fast");  //Slide Up Effect

            }
        });


        $("#storagetype").change(function(){

            if ($(this).val() == "domestic" ) {

                $("#hidedomestic").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect

            } else {

                $("#hidedomestic").slideUp("fast"); //Slide Up Effect

            }
        });
    });

    /* ]]> */

    </script>


    <div class="contactform">
    <div class="forminside">
    <div id="apDiv1">

    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" form action="page2.php"  onsubmit="return formCheck(this); "> 

    <div class="detailscolumn1"><h3></h3>
<br/>
<br/>

   <div class="storagetype">
            <div class="input select">
             <div class="labelfortype">
      <label for="storagetype">    select your business type</label>    </div><!--end of labelfortype class-->
                    <select name="storagetype" id="storagetype">
                <option value="">(select)</option>
                <option value="domestic">domestic</option>
                <option value="student">student</option>
                </select>
        </div>
       </div><!--end of storagetype class-->

     <div class="hiddenreason">   
        <div class="hide" id="hidedomestic"><!-- this select box will be hidden at first -->

            <div class="input select">
 <div class="labelforreason"> <label for="reasonstorage">reason for business</label></div><!--end of labelfortype class-->

                <select name="reason2" id="reason1">
                    <option value="">(select)</option>
                    <option value="moving">moving</option>
                    <option value="diy/home improvements">diy/home improvements</option>
                    <option value="decluttering">decluttering</option>
                    <option value="other">other</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
       </div><!--end of hidden reason--> 

      <div class="hiddenreason">  
       <div class="hide" id="hidestudent"><!-- this select box will be hidden at first -->
            <div class="input select">
  <div class="labelforreason"> <label for="reasonstorage">reason for business</label></div><!--end of labelfortype class-->

                <select name="reason3" id="reason2">
                    <option value="">(select)</option>
                    <option value="holiday">holiday</option>
                    <option value="moving">moving</option>
                    <option value="other">other</option>

                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div><!--end of hidden reason-->    






    </div><!--end of detailscolumn1-->



    </form></div>

    </div><!--end of forminside-->
    </div><!--end of contactform-->
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: try adding `0` as value if not selected, it's easier to check against it, then make sure you disable the `select` element that's hidden, finally check for the values only if they're not disabled...

Comment: @webeno thanks for your comment. value 0 is already there. The problem I am having is related to the validator above. It expects both hidden dropdown selection to be chosen. But only one of them can be chosen, either the ones related to domestic or student.

Comment: you got hung up on the `0` there... have a look at the 2nd part of what i wrote... ;)

Comment: thanks for that @webeno That makes sense. And how do I disable a select when it is hidden and check the values only if they're not disabled? I am still learning this subject hence appreciate the help a lot.

Comment: i provided an answer... the reason i didn't want to do it before is that i didn't quite see in your js function as to where you're doing the validation against the actual values of the select... i still don't know, so i added a generic response to that... hope it will help...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you disable the select that's hidden like this:

```
$("#storagetype").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "student" ) {
        $("#hidestudent").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect
        $("#reason2").prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $("#hidestudent").slideUp("fast");  //Slide Up Effect
        $("#reason2").prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

(apply the same to the other one)

...then check against disabled status of the input when you do your validation (honestly, I couldn't figure out from your js code where you're doing that, so I'm giving a general example here):

```
if ($('#test').prop('disabled') == true) {
    // do stuff if true
} else {
    // do stuff if false
}
```

**EDITED:** Something must be inherently wrong with your js code (and sorry, I couldn't figure out what exactly) but when I tested it, it always returned the error message, even if I deleted the lines hiding the hidden divs and allowed them to display, then selected values for all.

Also there was no email field (as specified and checked against in your js code - I added it) and there is no submit button either (added too).

See my test here: http://jsfiddle.net/Pk6SP/